# validating post params in api controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-api

Is there a recommended way to validate any input parameters in a controller action for a rails 4 API?

I know I can whitelist parameters, but what if I want to check if they have provided required values?

Please assume there will be no model validations and that I have to validate the POST JSON in the controller.

As an example lets use a create Person example JSON.

```
{
  "person": {
    "firstname": "Joe",
    "lastname": "Bloggs",
    "age": "99",
    "starsign": "virgo",
    "address": {
      "line1": "123 street",
      "city": "NYC",
      "zip": "90210"
    }
  }
}
```

Lets say all these fields were required, what would be the best way to check they had a value (forget about checking numericality ect, just presence of).  And also return an error message if one or more is missing.

I know a model validation would be the best way to do this if I was creating a Person like this:

```
Person.new(params)
```

but I am actually not doing that so I need another way to check the values!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/ruby-json-schema/json-schema will satisfy your need. It can validate a json data depending on supplied schema.

Comment: Thanks will try this out

Answer (score 0):

What you would do in the controller action is write something like

```
 params.require(:person).require(:firstname, :lastname)
```

This will throw an error if the person param is not supplied, you should then probably catch that error and preform the desired behavior, which should include notification to the user that the person param was not supplied.

Comment: I didn't know this was possible and I will check and see how it works..

Comment: yea I was using this the other day to validate end points for an rails API